# std::vector::assign equivalent for QVector

Tags: c++, qt

I have a C-style array, and I want to assign it to a QVector. If I were using std::vector, I would have used `assign()`:

```
int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
std::vector<int> v;
v.assign(arr, arr + sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int));
```

But for `QVector` I couldn't find a similar `assign()` method, or any range-accepting constructor.

I've already coded a for-loop to do it, but I was surprised that there wasn't such a basic function, is that really so, or is there an equivalent?

Comment: Just as a side note, in your example I wouldn't even use `assign`, but `vector`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Qt's [qCopy()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtalgorithms.html):

```
int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
QVector<int> v(5);
qCopy(arr, arr+5, v.begin());
```

Or you can use `std::copy()` of course.

```
int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
QVector<int> v(5);
std::copy_n( &arr, 5, v.begin() );
// or more general:
QVector<int> v2;
std::copy(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), std::back_inserter(v2));
// without begin/end
std::copy(arr, arr + 5, std::back_inserter(v2));
```

Comment: This doesn't have the same effect. It pushes new elements at the back. It only works if the `QVector` is empty to begin with.

Comment: @juanchopanza It has the same effect as the `vector`-based code the OP is replicating, though you are right in principle.

Comment: Right, but there would be no need to call `assign` in OP's code, so I am guessing they want to replace the contents of any vector, empty or not.

Comment: @juanchopanza Time to roll-out the `overwrite_or_append_iterator_adaptor`.

Comment: @pmr Err... And what's that?

Comment: @cmannett85 An OutputIterator like `back_insert_iterator`. The difference is that it overwrites as long as there is storage and then starts using `push_back`. It will perform a little worse due to the extra check, but very safe to use.

Comment: @cmannett85 I just found out Qt has its own function `qCopy()`, I updated the answer to use it instead.

Comment: @sashoalm Why did you delete the other methods!? Roll your edit back and *add* `qCopy` to the list.

Answer (score 1):

There is [fromStdVector()](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qvector.html#fromStdVector), which allows you to create a `QVector` from an `std::vector`:

```
int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
std::vector<int> v;
v.assign(arr, arr + sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]));
QVector<int> qvec = QVector<int>::fromStdVector(v);
```

Comment: I don't think this is what OP wants. He wants to assign the C-style array to the `QVector`. He doesn't want to assign a `vector` to a `QVector`.

Comment: The only problem is that we create and destroy a temporary object (i.e. performance).

Comment: @pmr Though converting the array into a `std::vector` could be followed by a conversion from `std::vector` to `QVector`, but I agree that this is probably inferior to a simple `std::copy` (especially regarding performance). But this way you could do it in only 1 single initialization line, instead of initialization followed by copying (of course only if dropping this whole `assign` madness for a properly initialized temporary `std::vector`).

Comment: Yes, it is the easiest to write. In fact, I'll be using it in my own code because that part of my code executes only once and the array is fairly small.

Comment: @sashoalm Just be sure to use `QVector<int> qvec = QVector<int>::fromStdVector(std::vector<int>(arr, arr+sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])));` directly.

Answer (score -2):

for simple types (e.g. int, char, void* ...etc), you can take the advantage of ::memcpy

```
int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

const int CNT = sizeof( arr ) / sizeof( int );
QVector<int> v( CNT );

// memcpy may be faster than std::copy_n in some compiler
::memcpy( v.data(), arr, CNT * sizeof( int ) );
```

for objects (e.g. std::string ), write a loop to copy the objects from arr to v

then just invoke the copy-constructors one-by-one

e.g.

```
std::string arr[] = { std::string("a"), std::string("b"), std::string("c") };
const int CNT = sizeof( arr ) / sizeof( std::string );
QVector<std::string> v( CNT );
for( size_t i = 0; i < CNT ; ++i )
    v[i] = arr[i];
```

As the copy constructor for each object in arr must be invoked one-by-one, I am sure there won't be a faster solution ( even you use the std::copy() ).

And the above code may result smaller code size when compared to std::copy in some compilers.

Comment: memcpy wouldn't work for a vector of std::strings, though. This code could lead to potential bugs.

Comment: *Never* use anything like memset on a C++ container class. Just don't.